# Values of radio_button_tag comes in a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radio-button

Need data returned as 
`"results"=>[{"radio_result"=>"true"}, {"radio_result"=>"false"}...]`
Currently have code:

```
@results.each_with_index do |result, index|    
  = radio_button_tag "results[][radio_result][#{index}]", true, result.radio_result?, id: "results__radio_result_#{index}_true"
  = label_tag "results[][radio_result][#{index}][false]", 'Yes'
  = radio_button_tag "results[][radio_result][#{index}]", false, !result.radio_result?, id: "results__radio_result_#{index}_false"
  = label_tag "results[][radio_result][#{index}][true]", 'No'
```

It kinda works but returns data in wrong format (`"results"=>[{"radio_result"=>{"0" => "true"}}, {"radio_result"=>{"0" => "false"}}...]`

Changing code to `= radio_button_tag "results[][radio_result]`(removing #{index} from it) should have fixed it - but instead - my labels are not showing up anymore

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you move the `index` earlier?

```
= radio_button_tag "results[#{index}][radio_result]"
```

That being said, I can't help but feel like maybe there's a more Railsy way to accomplish this. I'm not sure off the top of my head, but maybe something like:

```
= f.fields_for result do |result_fields|
  = result_fields.radio_button true, checked: result.radio_result?
  = result_fields.radio_button false, checked: !result.radio_result?
```